# Print function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, visual-studio-2013

I'm a beginner that just learn how to do coding and I happened to need a print function in my asp.net school project. (c#) is there anyone that can show me an example and guide me along? I'm currently using visual studio 2013 for my project. It's quite a trouble when the vs doesn't provide printDialog and etc. I want to print a page. Example I retrieved data from my database and I have a print button and when clicked, i want it to print the whole page.
Thanks so much!

Comment: What are you trying to print? Text from your application, pictures, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing some details that we need to help you. What are you printing? Is this a web project? If so, by "print" do you mean to trigger the browser's built-in print dialog? Please edit your question and provide more detail so we can offer assistance.

Comment: I'm trying to print a page. Like example I retrieve data from my database and i use a print button. when clicked, i want it to print the whole page.

Comment: Visual Studio won't provide print dialog. Instead, you renter content to a browser. Then you use browser's Print feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to launch the print dialog

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Crystal Reports** in Visual Studio 2010. Add your project to dataset and print button is prepared. If you want to use Visual Studio 2013 (it doesn't support Crystal Report) you can add your form or your page **Report Viewer** from Toolbox, design your report and select your dataset, choose report and set your view.